# Testing Dataprovider specific row

Tags: java, testng, dataprovider

Is there a way to pass a specific dataprovider row when I'm trying to debug a test

I have an excel file like this

- row1
- row2
- row3

and my test will use each row to be executed,

But, how can I specify row3 when I want to debug my test?

Answer (score 0):

Except modifying the data provider code or the data file, you can create a conditional breakpoint or a breakpoint with invocation counter at the beginning of your test method.